# Null value is getting stored instead of proper value at testcase level in groovy soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

Hi I have been trying to store value at test case level through groovy. Condition is also known to me; and i am for and if loop as it is a number of similar blocks.

Below is the response:

```
    "planDetailsList":    [
            {
         "ComponentId": "63026",
         "TypeCode": "P",
         "SubTypeCode": "A",

      },
            {
         "ComponentId": "63027",
         "TypeCode": "P",
         "SubTypeCode": "B"

      },
            {
         "ComponentId": "63029",
         "TypeCode": "P",
         "SubTypeCode": "C"

      },
            {
         "ComponentId": "63030",
         "TypeCode": "P",
         "SubTypeCode": "D"


      }
   ]
```

I am using the below script:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

for(i=0; i < jsonSlurper.planDetailsList.size(); i++){
if(jsonSlurper.planDetailsList[i].SubTypeCode == "C"){
def x = context.testCase.setPropertyValue('CmpnntId_H', jsonSlurper.planDetailsList[i].ComponentId.toString())
log.info x
}
```

Its not storing any(null) value at TestCase Level for the ComponentId. Can you tell me whats wrong is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
def json = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def id = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json).planDetailsList.find { it.SubTypeCode == "C" }?.ComponentId
if (id) {
    context.testCase.setPropertyValue('CmpnntId_H', id)
}
```